# Matlab Code should stop duplicates, but duplicates still occur

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a program that will find the outline of a figure by finding if points around an original point is within a boundary of the original point. I have tried to write a section that will prevent points to look at points already included in the outline (using variables a,b,c,d). The current code I have is

```
while 1
    [m M] = size(already_boxed);
    x=0;

    for n = 1:m
        a=0;
        b=0;
        c=0;
        d=0;
        for w = 1:m
            if already_boxed(w,:) == [(already_boxed(n,1)+1), already_boxed(n,2)]
                a=1;
            end
            if already_boxed(w,:) == [(already_boxed(n,1)-1), already_boxed(n,2)]
                b=1;
            end
            if already_boxed(w,:) == [already_boxed(n,1), (already_boxed(n,2)+1)]
                c=1;
            end
            if already_boxed(w,:) == [already_boxed(n,1), (already_boxed(n,2)-1)]
                d=1;
            end
        end
        if a==0
            if subimages((already_boxed(n,1)+1), already_boxed(n,2))<subimages(already_boxed(n,1),already_boxed(n,2))*0.9 && subimages((already_boxed(n,1)+1), already_boxed(n,2))>subimages(already_boxed(n,1),already_boxed(n,2))*1.1 
                already_boxed = [already_boxed; (already_boxed(n,1)+1), already_boxed(n,2)];
                x=1;
            end
        end
        if b ==0
            if subimages((already_boxed(n,1)-1), already_boxed(n,2))<subimages(already_boxed(n,1),already_boxed(n,2))*0.9 && subimages((already_boxed(n,1)-1), already_boxed(n,2))>subimages(already_boxed(n,1),already_boxed(n,2))*1.1 
                already_boxed = [already_boxed; (already_boxed(n,1)-1), already_boxed(n,2)];
                x=1;
            end
        end
        if c==0
            if subimages(already_boxed(n,1), (already_boxed(n,2)+1))<subimages(already_boxed(n,1),already_boxed(n,2))*0.9 && subimages(already_boxed(n,1), (already_boxed(n,2)+1))>subimages(already_boxed(n,1),already_boxed(n,2))*1.1 
                already_boxed = [already_boxed; already_boxed(n,1), (already_boxed(n,2)+1)];
                x=1;
            end
        end
        if d ==0
            if subimages(already_boxed(n,1), (already_boxed(n,2)-1))<subimages(already_boxed(n,1),already_boxed(n,2))*0.9 && subimages(already_boxed(n,1), (already_boxed(n,2)-1))>subimages(already_boxed(n,1),already_boxed(n,2))*1.1 
                already_boxed = [already_boxed; already_boxed(n,1), (already_boxed(n,2)-1)];
                x=1;
            end
        end
    end

    if x == 0
        break
    end
end
```

Right now, the code will go on forever since it keeps on checking points that are in the online. For example, the variable 'already_boxed' will contain the doubles:

```
119,288
120,288
118,288
119,289
119,287
119,288
```

I don't know why 119,288 shows up twice, and I only want it to show up once. How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to compare the new pixel to the first one. At some point you have gone all the way around the object, and end up at the first pixel again. That is when you stop.

Comment: What I want it to do is to start with one point that is on the outline, and find points adjacent close to it's value, and keep repeating the process until there are no more points to add (when ```x==0```, there hasn't been any points added during its loop so it stops.)

Comment: Going around an outline you can always keep going, if you don't check whether you've already visited the points or not. That said, I don't follow your code at all, so don't really know how to fix it. Usually when tracing an outline you go around the outline in one direction, and at some point you reach the first point again. That is when you stop. In [this blog post of mine](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/324) you can read about the standard algorithm for tracing an outline.